# How do i format date in input into words in php

Tags: php

This is where I will select date.

```
<input type = "date" name = "date" id = "date" placeholder = "select date">
```

If I select date the value is something like this 01/01/2016 and what I want is to turn it to January 1 2016. How do i do that?

Comment: `$date = new DateTime('01/01/2016'); echo $date->format('F j Y');`

Answer (score 0):

```
date('l jS \of F Y');
```

You can add also hour minutes ...

```
date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
```